# React Native Push Notifications not appearing in settings

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I am new to react native and I am trying to set up push notifications via iOS.

I have installed pushNotificationios and followed the instructions given. I have also signed up as an Apple Developer.

When I run my app the push notifications don't seem to work. When I go into my iPhone settings and click on the app it does not display notifications.

[image: settings]

Here is my code

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

const configure = () => {
 PushNotification.configure({

   onRegister: (token) => {
    console.log('TOKEN:', token);
     //process token
   },

   onNotification: (notification) => {
     // process the notification
     console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
     // required on iOS only
     notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
   },

   permissions: {
     alert: true,
     badge: true,
     sound: true
   },
  
   popInitialNotification: true,
   requestPermissions: true,

 });
};


 export {
    configure,
   };
```

Comment: Is this on the simulator or on an actual device

Comment: I have tried it on both

Comment: Have you added "push notifications" capabilities (xcode->target->signing & capabilities)?

Comment: did you receive any permission box on iphone?

Comment: are you calling configure() function in any file?

Comment: yes in my index file, I have added push notifications and no I did not receive any permission box on my iphone

Comment: can you add index.js code I think there is maybe a problem

Answer (score 0):

I have your package has some problem with permission

you can use [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions#checknotifications) package to get notification permission

```
import {requestNotifications} from 'react-native-permissions';

requestNotifications(['alert', 'sound']).then(({status, settings}) => {
  // …
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your XCode Notification settings
   [image]
2. Try to ask permission in your FirstPage as below. not index.

```
const MainPage = {} => {
  useEffect(() => {
    PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions(['alert', 'badge', 'sound']);
  }, [])
}
```

iOS: User cannot see the alarm option in preferences if user does not see the request Permission popup.

Android: Do not need asking permission.

Comment: @becky Do not worry about that. almost same.

Comment: invariant violation: invalid hook call. Hook can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: Just use `componentDidMount` if you use class component. The point is calling `PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your package name have some special character, but I had the same problem then you, and to resolve I needed to go to the xCode, Build Settings (of the project) and change the Product Name, because my Product Name had an accent (like "ó"), and that away wasn't a English name. Ridiculous but resolved